# 2 css trainsitions with varried delays

Tags: html, css

On my page is a orange container. If i go with my mouse over the box and wait 0.5 secounds the border radius (bottom-right & bottom-left) changes. Thats fine. But i want if i stay with my mouse 1 secound over the box, the border radius (top-right & top-left) changes.

- after 0.5 secounds delay, border radius (bottom-right & bottom-left)
- after 1 secound delay, border radius (top-right & top-left)

Here is [myPage](http://skeptar.bplaced.net/Homepage) + Code of the box:

```css
.text{
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    background-color: #FFCD57;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    transition: all 0.5s 0.3s;
}

.text:hover{
    border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
                <div class="text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                </div>
```

Comment: Yes give me some Keywords please. Or create me an example. Or dont help me :) You can choose :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `setTimeout()` for the second delay.

```js
var text = document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0];
var anim;

text.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  anim = setTimeout(function() {
    text.style.borderTopRightRadius = '40px';
    text.style.borderTopLeftRadius = '40px';
  }, 1500);
});

text.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  clearInterval(anim);
  text.style.borderTopRightRadius = '0';
  text.style.borderTopLeftRadius = '0';
});
```

```css
.text {
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: orange;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  background-color: #FFCD57;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  transition: all 0.5s 0.3s;
}
.text:hover {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
}
.top {
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
  et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla
  facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
</div>
```

Comment: A good solution to the problem, but the question didn't say the OP wanted to use javascript.

Comment: @CharliePrynn - The OP [didn't have a problem  with JavaScript solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032942/2-css-trainsitions-with-varried-delays/28033216?noredirect=1#comment44450920_28032942).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) For me its the best because, if i leave the div container all border-radius go to 0px at the same time. Thats really nice thanks!

Comment: I have one more ask. Can i combinate your answer with the answer of "Devin"? Maybe the transition effects with css and if i leave the div container with javascript? And this forum is really nice! :D So many friendly people's ^^

Comment: @Skeptar - I don't think combining CSS transition with the JavaScript solution would work.

Comment: ?? Yes it would work? Or no? Write yes or no please. I will ask again if i need help then ^^

Comment: @Skeptar - No, it won't work since the `transition-delay` will always be preserved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69222/discussion-between-skeptar-and-chipchocolate-py).

Answer (score 1):

You can separate different animations with commas, so in your example, you can change your CSS like this:

```
.text {
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    background-color: #FFCD57;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    transition: border-bottom-right-radius 0.5s 0.5s, border-bottom-left-radius 0.5s 0.5s, border-top-right-radius 0.5s 1s, border-top-left-radius 0.5s 1s;
    -webkit-transition: border-bottom-right-radius 0.5s 0.5s, border-bottom-left-radius 0.5s 0.5s, border-top-right-radius 0.5s 1s, border-top-left-radius 0.5s 1s;
    -moz-transition: border-bottom-right-radius 0.5s 0.5s, border-bottom-left-radius 0.5s 0.5s, border-top-right-radius 0.5s 1s, border-top-left-radius 0.5s 1s;
    -o-transition: border-bottom-right-radius 0.5s 0.5s, border-bottom-left-radius 0.5s 0.5s, border-top-right-radius 0.5s 1s, border-top-left-radius 0.5s 1s;
}
.text:hover {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
    border-top-left-radius: 40px;
    border-top-right-radius: 40px;
}
```

I've also included vendors extensions for further compatibility. While most browsers can read the non-vendor property, always make sure to include them for older browsers.

See [CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions#Multiple_animated_properties_example) for further info

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) If i leave i want that all border go at the same time to 0px. Is that with css doable? Or do i need javascript for this, like @chipChocolate did it?

Answer (score 1):

You can produce the desired effect by using CSS animation

Here is the code

```
  .text{
        text-align: justify;
        background-color: orange;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
        background-color: #FFCD57;
        padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        word-wrap:break-word;
        transition:all .5s ease;
    }
.text:hover{
-webkit-animation:first .5s linear .5s 1 forwards, second .5s linear 1s 1 forwards;
-moz-animation:first .5s linear .5s 1 forwards, second .5s linear 1s 1 forwards;
animation:first .5s linear .5s 1 forwards, second .5s linear 1s 1 forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes first{
    from{border-radius:0;}
    to{border-radius:40px 40px 0 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes second{
    from{border-radius:40px 40px 0 0;}
    to{border-radius:40px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes first{
    from{border-radius:0;}
    to{border-radius:40px 40px 0 0;}
}
@-moz-keyframes second{
    from{border-radius:40px 40px 0 0;}
    to{border-radius:40px;}
}
@keyframes first{
    from{border-radius:0;}
    to{border-radius:40px 40px 0 0;}
}
@keyframes second{
    from{border-radius:40px 40px 0 0;}
    to{border-radius:40px;}
}
```

If you have any questions just leave a comment and i'll be happy to answer
http://jsfiddle.net/8t0rgxk6/1/

Answer (score 0):

try applying the name of css property to transition [like described here](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_transitions.asp):

```
transition: border-bottom-right-radius 0.3s 0.5s,
            border-bottom-left-radius 0.3s 0.5s,
            border-top-right-radius 0.3s 1.0s,
            border-top-left-radius 0.3s 1.0s;
```